# Asus AC66R Wireless router won't recognized Western Digital My Passport external hard drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, wireless-router

I have an Asus AC66R Wireless router. It has 2 USB ports for sharing data on external hard drives.

I have a Seagate Free Agent (1TB) external hard drive. The router detects it, and it works fine. I have a Western digital (750GB) external hard drive, and the router will not detect it.

Both hard drives work fine with my Windows PC and a Mac. 
Both hard drives are powered by the router. They both light up and make spinning noises.

I've tried all permutations of USB cable and USB port.

Any ideas why the router will work with one USB external hard drive, but not the other?

Comment: Do you mean 750GB?

Comment: Could it be that the My Passport is formatted in HFS+ ?